# Connect Docker Networks to Different Interfaces with Same Gateway/Subnet

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, docker, linux-networking

*[I'm in way over my head, and I'm totally lost. I'm not sure if this is a general networking question, a Linux question, or a Docker question.]*

I'm building a monitoring solution for my home network. I have two modems (for irrelevant reasons) that feed into a gateway for load balancing, which services my network.

I'm trying to run a Docker image (in two containers) that queries each modem for statistics over an HTTP endpoint. Basically...this:

[image: next paragraph has description]

*That image does better than my text, but basically, I'm trying to set up a single Raspberry Pi (just one for cost and "simplicity") with multiple NICs: one directly to one modem, another directly to the other, and a third that connects to the home network. But I'm struggling to get the image running in two containers, with each connecting through their respective interfaces.*

But there's a kicker: the modems are each hard-coded with a specific IP address--192.168.12.1--that can't be changed.

So, I want to set up Container #1 so that when *it* calls out to that IP, it routes through NIC #1, and Container #2 so that it goes through NIC #2.

I've been playing with IPvlan and MACvlan networking in Docker, trying options like this (Docker Compose):

```yml
networks:
  network-eth1:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth1
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.12.0/24
        gateway: 192.168.12.1

  network-eth2:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth2
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.12.0/24
        gateway: 192.168.12.1
```

But, as some may guess, the subnets aren't allowed to overlap:

> Error response from daemon: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space

It's clear that Docker is trying to go above-and-beyond in the type of network it's building...

- I don't need the containers to be able to talk to each other.
- I don't need them to be able to bind to inbound ports.
- I don't need them to reach the home network.
- I don't even care about querying anything else on the modem's LAN.

Ideally, the containers would just act like they were hooked up to their respective NICs, and that'd be it.

I've gathered through my research that I could end up needing to do something with iptables, and I had tried that previously, but I think I wasn't doing it right, and even so, I'd love for Docker Compose to manage it internally.

I've tried playing with the vlan syntax (`eth1.20`) and such, but as I said in my first line, I'm in way over my head and don't really know what that even does--but I know it doesn't seem to work for what I want, since the subnets still conflict.

It feels like maybe there's just a setting I need to include, so that Docker doesn't try to build its own network across them? It's almost like I want a Host network, but with a specific NIC.

I would *imagine* this isn't a ridiculously difficult question at its core, but I just don't know what to search for. My case with multiple modems having the same IP address is weird, but I imagine someone wanting something similar just to explicitly test integrity of multiple NICs, even on the same network.